# css opacity not functioning

Tags: html, css

What am i missing here? Opacity seems to do nothing.i have tried hex/rgba and no change. I have added class to tr and td. no change.....

attempt 1:

```
.done{
    background-color: rgba(0,175,51,5);
    color:white;
    opacity: 50;
    filter:Alpha(Opacity=50);
}
```

attempt 2:

```
 .done{
    background-color:#00AF33;
    color:white;
    opacity: 50;
    filter:Alpha(Opacity=50);
 }

<table align='left' width='95%' class='childTasks'>
   <tr class='done'>
    <td id='1' class='childData done' width='15%'>Frank</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwdrjokd/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opacity is a value between 0 and 1.  Try 0.5

```css
.done {
    background-color: rgba(0, 175, 51, 100);
    color:white;
    opacity: 0.25;
    filter:Alpha(Opacity=50%);
}
```

```html
<table align='left' width='95%' class='childTasks'>
    <tr class='done'>
        <td id='1' class='childData done' width='15%'>Frank</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i knew it was something simple....